# Fix for issues caused by latest security update from MS (Win 10 KB4056892)

Tags: vb6, activex, dcom

I have an application which uses Activex servers (written in VB6 - no flames please).

There is a workstation component and two activex server components. The global DCOM permissions on the machines are set to "Connect" and "Identify", the authentication on the server components is set to "None", and the identity associated with the activex servers in DCOM has full admin rights on the machine in question.

There are also entries in global dcom which grant Anonymous Login local and remote access so that callbacks between the client exe and activex server will function correctly.

In order to get this working with the client, VB6 has to make an explicit call to CoInitialize:

```
        Dim lngHr As Long
        Dim lngAuthn As Long
        lngAuthn = RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT
        blnSecurityCalled = True
        lngHr = CoInitializeSecurity(ByVal API_NULL, -1, _
            lngAuthn, ByVal API_NULL, _
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_ANONYMOUS, _
            API_NULL, EOAC_NONE, ByVal API_NULL)
       If (S_OK <> lngHr) Then
            MsgBox "CoInitializeSecurity failed with error code: 0x" _
            & Trim$(Str$(Hex(lngHr))), vbCritical, _
            "Application Initialization Failure"
            Exit Sub
```

This worked just fine prior to the latest update to Windows which introduced issues documented by MS. MS suggested replacing the RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE with RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, but that's not sufficient.

There's no error code returned from the Coinitialize call, as I shouldbe seeing the "CoinitializeSecurity Failed" message in this case.

Instead, a couple steps later when the reference to the server component must be created:

```
ErrSubject = "Calling ClsServer "
Set Server = CreateObject("ASIServer.clsServer")
```

This statement is failing. It returns an "Object Required" message. If I run the exact same code through the VB6 IDE (which doesn't run the Coinitialize), the application runs without an error.

This only occurs with the Windows 10 update installed. If I uninstall it, everything works again.

Just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to continue to use the application with this patch, as who knows when MS is going to officially fix the problem they created on Jan 3.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your suggestions.

I have confirmed that when Microsoft releases the update with the fix, it will resolve the problem.

They're in the process of rolling it out -- it's just not available for all versions of Windows as of yet. Anything older than Windows 8 won't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT` and `RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY` (instead of `RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_ANONYMOUS`) and see if that helps.